# Multiplicative combination algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, iteration

#### Problem:

Given a number n, is there an efficient algorithm to obtain a list of 2-combinations from the set {1...n}, sorted by the value of the product of the combination?

I need this in order to determine the largest product of two *-digit numbers that satisfies a certain condition. If the list is unsorted, I must first determine all combinations that satisfy the condition, then iterate through those to find the combination with the largest product, which is inefficient.

As an example, given n = 3, the combinations possible are:

```
Combination:      Product:
   3, 3              9
   3, 2              6
   3, 1              3
   2, 2              4
   2, 1              2
   1, 1              1
```

Sorted by the value of the product in descending order, this is:

```
Combination:      Product:
   3, 3              9
   2, 3              6
   2, 2              4
   1, 3              3
   1, 2              2
   1, 1              1
```

#### Extra background:

I just solved a Project Euler question regarding finding the largest palindromic number that is a product of two 3 digit numbers. My approach was to iterate downward from 999 (the largest 3 digit number) with two factors and find the product of each combination, additionally checking whether the number was palindromic:

```
def maxpal():
    for i in reversed(range(100,1000)):

        # Since we only want unique combinations, we only
        # need to iterate up to i

        for j in reversed(range(100,i)):   
            if str(i*j) == str(i*j)[::-1]:
                yield i*j

print max(maxpal())
```

Note that the first list in the example iterates over factors in exactly the same order as this code. My initial assumption was that since I was iterating downwards, the first palindrome I found would be the largest one. This is clearly not the case, since `j` iterates all the way to 100 before `i` is decremented.

I am looking for a way to iterate such that the values are yielded are in descending order, since this allows me to get the answer simply by invoking `next(maxpal)` once, which is much more efficient.

EDIT:

In the interests of not disqualifying a good answer in a language that isn't Python, I'm OK with an attempt in any language as long as you explain it so that I (or anyone else) can sufficiently understand it.

Comment: which question is this specifically?

Comment: @johnthexiii Q4 I think. It was a couple days ago, but I only got up to 11, so it's before that.

Comment: If this is Q4, then there's an easier way to go about it. A product of two k-digit numbers has exactly 2×k digits. You just need to generate the 2×k-digit palindromes (and do some filtering on them). The number of palindromes is quite small, and easy to determine if you use the distinguishing property of a palindrome.

Comment: @larsmans That was the first approach I took. I generated all possible palindromes in descending order, but then realised that finding n digit factors is ridiculously expensive (first find prime factors, then find multiplicative combinations of those that give n digit factors). The devil is in the `(and do some filtering on them)`

Comment: @larsmans - A product of two k-digit numbers has _at most_ 2×k digits, not _exactly_ (examples: 2×3 = 6; 20×25 = 500).

Comment: The factoring/filtering for P4 takes at most 900*sqrt(900) = 27000 steps using a naive algorithm (and actually much less than that). Are you trying to solve this problem for very large numbers?

Comment: @Asad It's not so expensive in this case. Do a Fermat factorisation, and stop when the larger factor candidate has become too large. Since the largest palindrome that is a product of two d-digit numbers is rather close to `10^(2*d)`, you don't need many steps.

Comment: @TedHopp I've assumed that 3-digit numbers start at 100; for the purposes of the PE problem, that doesn't matter.

Comment: @larsmans Then you still have some `2*k-1` digit products.

Comment: @DanielFischer: good point. Too late to edit my comment, unfortunately. (It's late at night here...)

Comment: @Asad It's too late now for me to translate into Python, so would a Haskell implementation be acceptable?

Comment: @DanielFischer I can read Haskell, so that's great, thanks. I've edited the question.

Comment: Note that the implementation in my answer runs in a couple of milliseconds, vs other answers which take several seconds.  My timing: `%timeit pal()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.7 ms per loop`

Comment: @jwpat7: drewk seems to have misunderstood my answer and his code trying to implement the heap based solution is not what my answer is about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a heap/priority Q.

Start with (n,n), insert in the heap. Your comparison function  = compare the products.

Whenever you extract (x,y), you insert (x-1,y) and (x,y-1) if needed (you can maintain a hashtable to check for dupes if you want).

Here is some quick (and ugly looking) code to demonstrate the above. Note that this is a lazy iterator, allowing us to do a next and stopping as soon as your condition is satisfied. (Note: Using larsman's suggestion (comment below) will make it better, but the idea is similar)

```
import heapq

def mult_comb(n):
    heap = []
    visited = {}
    visited[n*n] = True
    prod = n*n
    heapq.heappush(heap, (-prod, n, n))
    while prod > 1:
        (prod,x,y) = heapq.heappop(heap)
        yield -prod,x,y
        prod = -prod

        prod1 = (x-1)*y
        prod2 = x*(y-1)
        if not prod1 in visited:
            heapq.heappush(heap, (-prod1, x-1,y))
            visited[prod1] = True
        if not prod2 in visited:
            heapq.heappush(heap, (-prod2, x,y-1))
            visited[prod2] = True

def main():
    for tup in mult_comb(10):
        print tup

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Since the OP wants two-element subsets, it's better to insert (x-1,y) and (x-1,y-1) to enforce the constraint x<=y early on.

Comment: @larsmans: I misread your comment (and deleted my earlier comments, if that is confusing you :-)). You are probably right.

Comment: `heapq` will always have at its root the smallest value in the heap. However, the last value is not at all guaranteed to be the largest value. You would still need to sort it to get the largest value.

Comment: @Drewk: Think of it as a 2D matrix M[n,n] where M[i,j] = i*j. This has the Young's Tableau property: Every row and column is sorted. Now you want to traverse this matrix in sorted order. A way to do this is insert in a max heap and do the extract/insert as I outlined above. I don't understand your objection. I am answering the main question, not the background project Euler question.

Comment: Well you didn't have code when I made my comment, so it was an implementation comment. You code is great. +1

Comment: @drewk: Yeah, sorry that was not clear (and your comment and your answer was the reason I added the code!). Thanks!

Comment: @Knoothe: I timed this (at the bottom of my answer), and it is about 4X faster to find the first palindrome but 2X slower to find the whole list. I learned something new. Thanks!

Comment: @drewk: Thanks for trying that out. Yeah, if all we need is the top few, we should use this one. If you need all, simple looping and checking will likely be faster.

Answer (score 3):

The loop schema in the question is like

```
for i in reversed(range(100,1000)):
    for j in reversed(range(100,i)):   
        if str(i*j) is palindromic, yield i*j
```

and the requested solution is to find a way to deliver in descending order the same numbers as that loop tests.  The code above generates 404550 i,j pairs; 1231 of those pairs are palindromic; 2180 of the pairs are larger than the ultimate result 906609 = 913*993.

The methods suggested so far may generate all or many of the possible pairs; and those that generate only a few  of the possible pairs still test many more number pairs than necessary.

The following code, by contrast, tests only 572 pairs, of which 3 are palindromes.  It depends mainly on two observations: first, any six-digit palindrome is a multiple of 11 because any number with digit form `abccba` is equal to `a*100001 + b*10010 + c*1100`, and all three of 100001, 10010, and 1100 are multiples of 11.  Second, if our best find so far has value k and we are testing a given value of i with `i≤j` then there is no need to test any `j < k/i` or any `j<i`.

```
def pal():
    nTop = 1000;    best, jin, jpal = 0, 0, 0
    # Test pairs (i, j) with i <= j
    for i in range(nTop, nTop//10-1, -1):
        jDel = 11 if i%11 else 1
        jHi = (nTop//jDel)*jDel
        jLo = max(i, best//i) - 1;
        for j in range(jHi, jLo, -jDel):
            jin += 1
            if str(i*j)==str(i*j)[::-1] :
                jpal += 1
                best = max(best, i*j)
    return (best, jin, jpal)
```

With the above code, `pal()` returns the tuple (906609, 572, 3).

Comment: This is actually the fastest one here by a mile!

Comment: +1: But this is solving the project Euler question (filed under background :-)), and not the question that was actually asked (which is an interesting question in its own right).

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the set like so:

```
>>> n=3
>>> s={(min(x,y),max(x,y)) for x in range(1,n+1) for y in range(1,n+1)}
>>> s
set([(1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2), (1, 1)])
```

And sort it like this:

```
>>> sorted(s,key=lambda t: -t[0]*t[1])
[(3, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1)]
```

But you don't need to do it this way at all. Just use a nested comprehension:

```
>>> [(x,y) for x in range(3,0,-1) for y in range(3,x-1,-1)]
[(3, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1)]
```

Which leads to a one liner for that paticular problem:

```
print max(x*y for x in range(1000,100,-1) for y in range(1000,x-1,-1) 
          if str(x*y)==str(x*y)[::-1])
```

If you really want to do it the way you propose, you can use `bisect`:

```
def PE4():
    import bisect

    def ispal(n):
        return str(n)==str(n)[::-1]

    r=[]
    for x in xrange(1000,100,-1):
        for y in xrange(1000,x-1,-1):
            if ispal(x*y): bisect.insort(r,(x*y,x,y))

    return r[-1]
```

The list `r` ends up in increasing order since that is the only order supported by bisect.

You can also use `heapq`:

```
def PE4_4():
    import heapq

    def ispal(n): return str(n)==str(n)[::-1]

    r=[]
    for x in xrange(100,1001):
        for y in xrange(x,1001):
            if ispal(x*y): heapq.heappush(r,(-x*y,x,y))     

    return (-r[0][0],r[0][1],r[0][2])
```

If I time these:

```
import timeit

def PE4_1():
    def ispal(n): return str(n)==str(n)[::-1]
    return max((x*y,x,y) for x in xrange(1000,99,-1) for y in xrange(1000,x-1,-1) if ispal(x*y))

def PE4_2():
    import bisect
    def ispal(n): return str(n)==str(n)[::-1]
    r=[]
    for x in xrange(1000,99,-1):
        for y in xrange(1000,x-1,-1):
            if ispal(x*y): bisect.insort(r,(x*y,x,y))

    return r[-1]

def PE4_3():
    import bisect
    def ispal(n): return str(n)==str(n)[::-1]
    r=[]
    for x in xrange(100,1001):
        for y in xrange(x,1001):
            if ispal(x*y): bisect.insort(r,(x*y,x,y))

    return r[-1]

def PE4_4():
    import heapq
    def ispal(n): return str(n)==str(n)[::-1]
    r=[]
    for x in xrange(100,1001):
        for y in xrange(x,1001):
            if ispal(x*y): heapq.heappush(r,(-x*y,x,y))     

    return (-r[0][0],r[0][1],r[0][2])         

n=25
for f in (PE4_1,PE4_2,PE4_3,PE4_4):
    fn=f.__name__
    print fn+':'
    print '\t',f()
    res=str(timeit.timeit('{}()'.format(fn),setup="from __main__ import {}".format(fn), number=n))
    print '\t'+res+' seconds\n'
```

It prints:

```
PE4_1:
    (906609, 913, 993)
    10.9998581409 seconds

PE4_2:
    (906609, 913, 993)
    10.5356709957 seconds

PE4_3:
    (906609, 913, 993)
    10.9682159424 seconds

PE4_4:
    (906609, 913, 993)
    11.3141870499 seconds
```

Shows that the `bisect` method is marginally faster, followed by the max of a generator. `heapq` is the slowest method (marginally)

Long answer, but probably the best way to produce the order of list you want is to sort it that way:

---

I timed Knooth's solution and it is massively superior to find the first number with a constraint:

```
def PE4_6():
    def ispal(n): return str(n)==str(n)[::-1]
    def gen(n=1000):
        heap=[]
        visited=set([n*n])
        prod=n*n
        heapq.heappush(heap,(-prod,n,n))
        while abs(prod)>1:
            (prod,x,y)=heapq.heappop(heap)
            yield -prod,x,y
            p1,p2=(x-1)*y, x*(y-1)
            if p1 not in visited:
                heapq.heappush(heap, (-p1, x-1,y))
                visited.add(p1)
            if p2 not in visited:
                heapq.heappush(heap, (-p2, x,y-1))
                visited.add(p2)

    it=iter(gen())
    t=next(it)
    while not ispal(t[0]):
        t=next(it)

    return t
```

But slower to find the whole list.

Comment: But that actually generates all the values in order to find the maximum, because it does not generate them in descending order. (Of course, for numbers this size, that's not a problem on modern hardware. But it doesn't scale.)

Comment: This is much closer, since it finds the desired palindrome in 4 iterations, but it still doesn't output a list that is sorted by the magnitude of the product. For example, the first few outputs from the generator in your last snippet are: `[888888, 861168, 886688, 906609, 824428, 819918, 828828, 855558, 840048, 853358]`. It also doesn't strictly output combinations, since certain products will occur in the list multiple times (as a consequence of the fact that the second factor counts down from 1000 to x instead of from x to 100). Still, +1.

Comment: The way you are using the heap is missing the point of needing an iterator. See sample code in my answer. For instance, you only need to look at about 114,000 numbers to get to the 3rd largest palindrome, while in your implementation, you look at around a million, and then insert the palindromes into a heap. Care to compare it against my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Given a number n, is there an efficient algorithm to obtain a list of 2-combinations from the set {1...n}, sorted by the value of the product of the combination?

Not quite sure what you're after, but this is a simple way to code it in python:

```
n = SOME_INTEGER
from itertools import combinations
sorted(combinations(set(xrange(1,n+1)),2),key=lambda x: x[0]*x[1])
```

or, with largest product first:

```
sorted(combinations(set(xrange(1,n+1)),2),key=lambda x: x[0]*x[1],reverse=True)
```

Comment: The problem here is that you are first generating an unsorted list of combinations, *then* sorting them. The idea is to generate a sorted list.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you're after... has the merit of being compact at least, if not efficient ;)

Answer (score 0):

You know that (a, b) will always come before (a, c) when b > c.  So you can just keep one representative of each class [(a, b), (a, b-1), (a, b-2), ...], and choose among these.  Use a heap.  This implementation takes O(n^2*log(n)) time and O(n) space:

```
import heapq

def combinations_prod_desc(n):
    h = [(-i*i, i, i) for i in xrange(1, n+1)]
    h.reverse()

    while len(h) > 0:
        u = h[0]
        yield u
        b = u[2]
        if b <= 1:
            heapq.heappop(h)
            continue
        a = u[1]
        b -= 1
        heapq.heappushpop(h, (-a*b, a, b))
    return
```

Since Python 2.6, the heapq module has the merge algorithm built-in.  Leveraging that, we can get a one-line implementation of the same algorithm:

```
def combinations_prod_desc_compact(n):
    return heapq.merge(*[(lambda a : ((-a*b, a, b) for b in xrange(a, 0, -1)))(a) for a in xrange(1, n+1)])
```

The following naive version of the above doesn't work due to oddities in the semantics of Python comprehensions.  If someone's interested in exploring Python's language specs, it would be interesting to look up the exact reason why the following code doesn't give the result we want even though it looks like it "should":

```
def combinations_prod_desc_nonworking(n):
    return heapq.merge(*[((-a*b, a, b) for b in xrange(a, 0, -1)) for a in xrange(1, n+1)])
```